# why does it go wrong after push_back?

Tags: c++, vector

The code here is simple:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("hello");
    string& x = v[0];
    v.push_back("world");
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is there a runtime error? Please explain it in detail.

Comment: According to the documentation of [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (did you even look at it?): _If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and **references** (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated._ (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 13):

Have a read through a reference : [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). Specifically the part that says :

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

When you pushed back the second string into the vector, it appears it had to re-allocate memory, because there wasn't enough capacity for the second string. This re-allocation moved the entire vector data elsewhere in memory - including the first string you pushed into it. So the reference to that first string became a dangling reference, and de-referencing it has undefined behavior.